# Glide image loading with redirect

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-volley, android-glide

I'm trying to load image from url using glide. But the url is redirection to another url and hence the image is not being displayed.

The url is of Amazon s3 and I'm using volley integration with glide

How can I handle this redirection?

```
public class CustomCache implements GlideModule {
@Override
public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    try {
        builder.setDiskCache(
                new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, 41943040)
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void registerComponents(Context context, final Glide glide) {
    RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue( // params hardcoded from Volley.newRequestQueue()
            new DiskBasedCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "volley")),
            new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack())) {
        @Override public <T> Request<T> add(Request<T> request) {
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, 1, 1));

            return super.add(request);
        }
    };
    queue.start();
    glide.register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new VolleyUrlLoader.Factory(queue));
}


}
```

Comment: 1st show how you do it

Comment: I'm just loading image with this :
 Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageview)
What else you need to now?

Comment: I mean how have you integrated it with volley

Comment: I have edited my question kindly check